# Checking for same value in rows and calculate corresponding total

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large s/sheet. Values in column A correspond to values in column B, C & D.

I need to combine some rows which have same value in column A and automatically calculates total of value in column B in all corresponding rows.

Then i need to delete all unnecessary rows

Any ideas how i can do this with some code?

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you post the code you've tried. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO's question guidelines.

Comment: What about values in columns C and D? For ColB, add a new column and use `SUMIF()` to sum all values in ColB by value in ColA. Copy/paste-values then use Data >> Remove Duplicates (selecting only ColA) to remove the "extra" rows

Comment: Columns C and D not really important - have tried SUMIF() but values in CoIA are not constant - could be that 5 rows have same value other times only 1 row.

Comment: Ok tried this code but it returns 0 - no idea why                       Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub
Sub DoCalculation()
Dim row As Integer, lastrow As Integer

' set the rownumber for the last row of your data
lastrow = 3621

Columns("f").ClearContents
prow = 2
For row = 2 To lastrow - 1
temp = Cells(row, 3)
For row2 = row To lastrow
If Cells(row2, 3) = temp Then
Cells(prow, 16) = temp
Cells(prow, 16) = Cells(prow, 6) + Cells(row2, 6)
End If
Next row2
If Cells(row + 1, 1) <> temp Then prow = prow + 1
Next row
Columns("f").ClearContents

End Sub

Answer (score -2):

I think that you can use Power Query or VBA. Probably you will be able to achieve this with formulas, but it will be not flexible. With Power QUery you can combine data from multiple sources, clean and transform and even load directly into PowerPivot model. If you will have some detailed information please let me know. If you can upload the sample workbook with your data i will be able to provide you some more information.

Comment: Should be able to do this with vba but have difficulty with code - do not know power query unfortunately & cannot upload file

Comment: You can simply install Power Querry and try on your own. It's powerful and easy and you will not have to write any code.

Comment: OK Seems Power Query is only compatable with excel 2010 onwards - unfortunately i still run 2007 - so VBA it is